# BotFramework: Get probability score of IntentDialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

Is it possible to get the probability score (0-1) of the IntentDialogs? So I want to find out how confident the bot is about answering the question, and based on it I want to perform certain actions. How can I do that? I'm using `QnAMaker` and also some hardcoded dialogs.

**Sample code:**

```
var qnarecognizer = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: '', 
    subscriptionKey: '',
    top:4});

var intentrecognizer = new builder.IntentDialog();

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [intentrecognizer, qnarecognizer] });
bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches('qna', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        var answerEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'answer');
        session.send(answerEntity.entity);
    }
]);

intents.matchesAny([/Test/i], [
        function (session) {
           session.send('This is not from QnA Maker.');
        }
]);

intents.onDefault( [
        function (session) {
           session.send('Sorry, I don\'t know that.');
        }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score is a property on the entity itself.  The following will respond by sending a message back to the user for each qna answer with the corresponding score:

```
intents.matches('qna', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        args.entities.forEach(function(element) {
            session.send('score=' + element.score + ':' + element.entity);
        }, this);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find `findBestMatch` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/9154040a34c46947b20d7d6ef323ab79b189a4c5/Node/core/src/dialogs/EntityRecognizer.ts#L220). As you can see you can get matches using the following:

```
var matches = EntityRecognizer.findAllMatches(choices, utterance, threshold);
```

And getting score of a match likes the following:

```
matches[i].score
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying EntityRecognizer is not defined. I'm not sure where and how I need to define it.